# Is it possible to remove the root directory?

Tags: unix, rm

I noticed in the documentation for `rm` as obtained by `rm --help` the following flag:

```
--no-preserve-root  do not treat `/' specially
```

What does this mean? Is it actually possible to delete the root directory, *apart from its contents*? What consequences would that have?

Comment: Yes, they put in place a protection from people who try `rm -rf /`.  They put that in place because yes, you can and you're system will be useless.

Comment: In my understanding, `rm -rf /` deletes *the contents* of the root directory; but wouldn't the root directory itself still exist?

Comment: @gerrit: Yes, it would. But this command is precisely why the "preserve root" mode was added: *rm* refuses to operate recursively on `/` unless you add the `--no-preserve-root` option.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You cannot delete the root directory itself. However, you can use rm's *recursive* mode to delete everything *in* that directory – the infamous `rm -rf /` command.

The "preserve root" mode stops `rm` from recursively operating on the root directory:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /
rm: it is dangerous to operate recursively on ‘/’
rm: use --no-preserve-root to override this failsafe
```

The `--preserve-root` option was added to GNU *rm* in 2003 (commit 9be74f6f125b2be), and was made the [default behavior](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/coreutils/+bug/174283) in 2006 (commit aff5a4f2ab86f).

Some say it is because pranksters in [#ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/support/community/chat) kept telling newbies to run `rm -rf /` – and many did. Some say it is because [it is too easy to mistype](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Treating-_002f-specially.html) `rm -rf / tmp/junk`. Some say it is to prevent accidents when running `rm -rf $dir/` when $dir is empty. <del>All we know is, he's called th</del>

Either way, it is [part of POSIX requirements](https://superuser.com/a/742735) nowadays. Solaris `rm` [also has similar protection](http://web.archive.org/web/20110531035849/http://blogs.oracle.com:80/jbeck/date/20041001), as does [OpenBSD](https://github.com/openbsd/src/commit/c11d908c7069eb03d103482ce1d0227f3d47b349).

Comment: Did you actually dare to type that for real?

Comment: Linux is cheap, as are old computers. Admit that you've done it on a decommissioned system to see how to quickly create disk space. And the answer is yes.