# Is this a valid macOS bash command?

Tags: macos

If I wanted to get rid of everyone on my computer and I just typed in the following into the terminal:

```
sudo rm -rPf --no-preserve-root
```

would that work or is something wrong with my syntax? I added `--no-preserve-root` because I want it to get everything and I read that `rm -r` doesn't work by itself if no directory is specified

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a scenario where rm -rf -no-preserve-root is needed?](http://superuser.com/questions/742334/is-there-a-scenario-where-rm-rf-no-preserve-root-is-needed)

Comment: `--no-preserve-root` This option
    is not recommended unless you really want to remove all the files
    on your computer.

Comment: This command is missing a path, but it will most certainly get rid of every*thing*, but most certainly not every*one* currently logged on.

Comment: Second to what Daniel B said – please clarify whether you are looking to get rid of everyTHING or everyONE.

Comment: I want to get rid of absolutely everything

Answer (score 0):

`sudo rm -rf` will get rid of any file or folder that you feed to it (unless it is a file protected by the system-integrity system of OSX). -P will overwrite the empty space, but I would not advise using it if you have an SSD as it will only reduce the lifespan of it.

As to your question: do you want to get rid of all accounts? Or Simply everything? Because all I can tell you is that as far as I am aware your proposal or a equivalent like `sudo rm -rfP /` will certainly ruin your entire system.

I'd say, go for a clean install via OS Recovery if you want to start over with a fresh install. If you only want to delete the accounts, use the appropriate settings in 'System Preferences'.